# Unable to bypass some kind of fingerprinting system to a login page with Puppeteer / NodeJS

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, fingerprinting

That issue has been driving me crazy for the last days! I am trying to access the login page of this website below using Puppeteer and it will simply not work.

Home page : https://www.kijiji.ca
Login page : https://www.kijiji.ca/t-login.html

Here's my basic script :

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
async function main(){

  var browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless : false
  });

  var page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto("https://www.kijiji.ca");

  await page.waitForSelector('[title="Sign In"]');

  await page.click('[title="Sign In"]');

}
main();
```

The login page won't load! The page appears blank, however in the source code there's a script tag that runs on normal browsers, but not automated ones. Here's a couple of things I tried :

- Tried headless and headful, didn't work
- WORKS UNDER puppeteer-firefox, only one it works with (I am trying to avoid using it since it is no longer updated)
- Ran it through multiple user-agents, didn't work
- Ran it through multiple proxies, didn't work
- Tried with Selenium (chrome driver, firefox driver), didn't work
- Tried with puppeteer-extra and puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth (All pages load then disappear with that enabled)

There must really be something I am missing here! Would any one here have any idea of what else I can try!

Thanks you so much everyone!

Comment: One thing you could try is to 'reset' the `window.navigator = {}` property before you navigate to these URLs. You can use [this website](https://intoli.com/blog/not-possible-to-block-chrome-headless/chrome-headless-test.html) and [this website](https://bot.sannysoft.com/) to test your settings. Also try deleting the webdriver.

Comment: @LukaKralj thank you for leading me on the right path! I used the sannysoft website you shared with me to realize that `navigator.webdriver` that was at fault. After trying to reset it manually, I found this page [link](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/6725) to set two arguments to Puppeteer! It seems to have done the trick! Thank you very much  !

Comment: Perfect, glad I could help!

Comment: I implemented the codes from the above links but it only got worse, I'll eventually make a question post.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. I see it's trying to make a ws connection to 127.0.0.1:5900 / 127.0.0.1:5903 which is pretty sneaky. These are vnc ports so if you're running vnc turn it off.

Also regarding firefox, playwright-firefox is being maintained, and there's also a playwright-webkit.

Comment: It's trying to connect to 127.0.0.1? Is it trying to detect if the browser is running in a VM?

Comment: Maybe, my thought was that people might run that on a remote VPS